# Password fields won't validate properly PHP

Tags: php, validation

I'm making a registration form but I can't get the "Confirm Password" field to validate. The field "Password" validates but "Confirm Password" doesn't.

MY PHP code:

```
    $ps_m="";
    $ps1_m="";
    $pass=isset($_POST["pass"]) ? $_POST["pass"]: "" ;
    $pass1=isset($_POST["pass_1"]) ? $_POST["pass_1"] : "";   

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if($pass===""){$ps_m="<span class=\"error\">Please enter Password</span>";}
    if(!$pass1===$pass){$ps1_m="<span class=\"error\">Password does not match</span>";}
    }
```

And Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter Password"/><?php echo $ps_m;?>
<input type="password" name="pass_1" placeholder="Confirm Password"/><?php echo $ps1_m;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$ps_m="";
$ps1_m="";
$pass=isset($_POST["pass"]) ? $_POST["pass"]: "" ;
$pass1=isset($_POST["pass_1"]) ? $_POST["pass_1"] : "";   

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if($pass===""){$ps_m="<span class=\"error\">Please enter Password</span>";}
    if($pass1!==$pass){$ps1_m="<span class=\"error\">Password does not match</span>";}
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Have been trying to get this to work for almost 2 days now!!  Lol I made such a stupid mistake! xD